# Sum of Columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 columns in my table, `Debit` and `Credit`. I am doing `Debit - Credit`.

If the sum of  `Debit - Credit` is >= 0, then add value in Debit else Credit.

Now how to add values in specific columns?

I am using this query

```
SELECT
    ActName,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) >= 0 THEN 'DebitAmount'
         WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) <= 0 THEN 'CreditAmount' END
FROM 
    TblAWSLocalTrans
GROUP BY
    ActName
ORDER BY
    ...
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you share your table data and your expected output

Comment: Please stop making bad edits, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off.  If I understand correctly, you want to aggregate credits/debits over accounts, and then report a credit or debit where appropriate.  When an account has a credit, then 0 should be displayed for the debit, and vice-versa should the account have a debit.

```
SELECT
    ActName,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CreditAmount - DebitAmount) >= 0
         THEN SUM(CreditAmount - DebitAmount)
         ELSE 0 END AS TotalCreditAmount,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) > 0
         THEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount)
         ELSE 0 END AS TotalDebitAmount
FROM TblAWSLocalTrans
GROUP BY ActName
ORDER BY ActName;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank it worked but values in credit showing -ve how to show it in positive way

Comment: @SyedMohsinAli Sorry, I had a small typo in my logic.  It seems to be working now.

Comment: Your query is working perfect for me. Further more can you please help me how to write this query on button click to fill grid in asp.net webform

Comment: @SyedMohsinAli I don't know much ASP.net, but I can suggest that you open a new question for that.  And, in that question, just focus on the ASP part, assume that you already have the query working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query will be like below

```
SELECT
    ActName,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) >= 0
    THEN  SUM(DebitAmount+CreditAmount)
    else  SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount)  END
FROM TblAWSLocalTrans
GROUP BY ActName
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think your Query is wrong.follow this

```
SELECT
    ActName,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) >= 0
    THEN  SUM(DebitAmount+CreditAmount)
    else  SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount)  END
FROM TblAWSLocalTrans
GROUP BY ActName
```

Comment: It would be better answer if you tell what's OP wrong in query and give explanation in your query